# NCBIWWW.qblast parsing xml files

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, blast, error-messaging

I am using biopython to (attempt to) write a script that will take my downloaded Sanger sequencing results from Genewiz (multiple sequences downloaded into a single FASTA file), create a new file with the sequence trimmed to my desired length, run the trimmed sequences on BLAST, and list the species of the top hit. As I am pretty new to bioinformatics and programming I am working through each of these parts step-by-step using the biopython cookbook as a framework. I have managed to get my trimmed sequences in a new file and BLAST to run (is it always that slow?) but am getting stuck now on parsing. Any help would be appreciated! I will edit/post more questions as I work through this program, but one step at a time.

Code so far:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\asmit\\Desktop\\Sequences\\Cytb')
print("Current folder:   " + os.getcwd())
import Bio
from Bio import SeqIO
import glob

for filename in glob.iglob('*download.fasta'):
    name = str(filename)
    newname = str(filename.strip("_download.fasta") + "_trim.fasta")
    print("File procesing: " + name)
    with open(newname, "w") as f: 
       for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(open(name, mode = 'r'), "fasta"):
               f.write(str(">" + seq_record.id + "\n"))
               x = 31
               while x < 411:
                       f.write(str(seq_record.seq[x:x+50])+ "\n")
                       x = x + 50

print("All files trimmed.")

from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
                    
for filename in glob.iglob('*trim.fasta'):
    name = str(filename)
    newname = str(filename.strip(".fasta") + ".xml")
    print("Running BLAST on " + name)
    record = open(name).read()
    result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", record, hitlist_size=1)
    print("BLAST on " + name + " is complete.")
    with open(newname, "w") as out_handle: 
            out_handle.write(result_handle.read())
            out_handle.close()
            result_handle.close()
    print(newname + " is ready for parsing.")

print("All files BLASTed")
```

Comment: Please show us an example of the BLAST results as well as the desired output.

Comment: My issue was running `NCBIWWW.qblast` directly from python. It apperently cannot be called directly because the request is too big(even with a single fasta sequence). I ran a quick batch script to merge my trimmed fasta files into one big fasta file, then uploaded that merged file to the NCBI website and downloaded the resulting XML file.