# NCBI Blast not running

Tags: python, biopython, blast, ncbi

I am trying to run online ncbi blast on python.

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW 
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML 
from Bio import SeqIO

record = SeqIO.read(r"C:\Users\loops\Downloads\biopy_resources\Section1\Chap8\buccal_swab.unmapped1.fasta",format="fasta")
handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn","nt",record.seq)

blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(handle)
E_VALUE_THRESH = 0.0001
for blast_record in blast_records: 
    for alignment in blast_record.alignments: 
        for hsp in alignment.hsps: 
            if hsp.expect < E_VALUE_THRESH: 
                print(alignment.title) 
                print(alignment.length) 
                print(hsp.expect) 
                print(hsp.query[0:75]) 
                print(hsp.match[0:75]) 
                print(hsp.sbjct[0:75])
```

reading fasta file succeeded, but no results are displayed.
I think it's stuck here: handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn","nt",record.seq)

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW 
handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn","nt","8332116")
```

it does not work,either.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no error, maybe there is not result because the e-value if above the threshold? you could disable the if condition
OR
might relate to this problem of running slow within python eventually:
[NCBIWWW.qblast parsing xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107481/ncbiwww-qblast-parsing-xml-files)